# Array of observables type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am just curious, what will be the correct type of Observables array?

I tried:

```
let myObservables: Observable[] = new Array();
let myObservables: Observable<Array<any>> = new Array();
let myObservables: Observable<[]> = new Array();
```

but none of them are working.

I just want an array in which i can `push` observables so that i can pass it to `Observable.forkJoin(myObservables)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay i found it. The following are two correct ways to do it:

```
let myObservables: Observable<any>[] = new Array();
let myObservables: Array<Observable<any>> = new Array();
```

If anyone finds it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

`const subscriptions: Observable<any>[] = [];`

Answer (score -1):

Could you not just do:

```
let myObservables: any = [];

Observable.forkJoin(myObservables)
```

Comment: Yes but i wanted to know the best practise for strict type checking. `Any` i try to use at last resort :)

Answer (score -2):

Use:

`let myObservables: Observable[] = [];`

Comment: Doesn't work, same issue as `let myObservables: Observable[] = new Array();` - I get this error: `Generic type 'Observable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`